# How to verify if an element is inside an ordered pair?

Tags: notation

The notation to verify if an element belongs to a set is $e \in E$.
But which notation should I use to verify if an element is part of an ordered pair? Is $a \in (a,b)$ valid (e.g., $1 \in (1,2)$)?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is an accepted standard notation for saying a particular element appears in an ordered pair. Certainly "$1 \in (1,2)$" is not accepted notation.

Comment: Although, some set theorists "construct" ordered pairs some sets as follows: $(x,y) = \{x,\{x,y\}\}$. In such a case, $1 \in (1,2)$ is true! :)

Comment: @BillCook:  Amusingly, though, $2 \not \in (1,2)$ by the same definition.

Comment: Thanks. In my case $V = { (a,b) | a \in A, b \in B, condition }$. Then, I need to verify if a given element is part of any $(a,b) \in V$. So $a \in (a,b)$ probably not apply and I'm not sure which notation to use.

Comment: In that case you're just asking if you belong to $\{ x \in A \;|\; \exists b \in B \mbox{ such that } (x,b) \in V \} \cup \{ x \in B \;|\; \exists a \in A \mbox{ such that } (a,x) \in V \}$

Comment: @RossMillikan :)

Comment: Yes, I think that $\{ x \in A | \exists b \in B such that (x,b) \in V\}$ is exactly what I need! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

As I stated in my comment above, I am not aware of any accepted standard notation for saying a particular element appears in an ordered pair.

That said, suppose we take the view that order $n$-tuples are "really" maps from $\mathbb{Z}_{>0} = \{1,2,3,\dots\}$ into our set $X$. Or more generally from an ordinal into $X$. (This sort of thing is done in field such as Topology where one runs into infinite Cartesian products).

From this viewpoint: $(a,b)=f$ where $f:\{1,2\} \to X$ and $f(1)=a$, $f(2)=b$. If we take this view $a, b \in \mathrm{Range}(f)$. So we could write $1 \in \mathrm{Range}(1,2)$.

However, try doing that without explaining yourself and you'll get some odd looks. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It certainly would solve the problem, but you are right when you say that it is not intuitive.

Since the order in not important for me $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ would have the same effect maybe I could say that V is a set of sets with 2 elements where one element belongs to A and the other belongs to B. Is something like: $V = \{\{a,b\} | a \in A, b \in B, condition\}$ valid?

Comment: Yes. Your $V$ will now be a set of subsets of size 2 (and 1 if $a=b$). So now instead of being a subset of $A \times B$, your $V$ will be a subset of the power set $\mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$.

Comment: Then your question becomes: Does there exist some $X \in V$ such that $a \in X$. :)

Comment: So, $V = \{\{a,b\}| a \in A, b \in B, f(a,b)>5 \}$ would create a set with subsets of size 2 (a and b are never equal). Then I can ask if $\exists \{a,b\} \in V | a' \in \{a,b\}$. The last question is, can I use that condition when building the set (f(a,b) could be a distance function for an example)? :)

Comment: Sure. That's a perfectly valid condition to put in the middle of a definition.